# Do adjectives in English satisfy a distributive property?

Tags: adjectives

I come from a math background, so I apologize if this question is trivial; I could not find any references about this.

In Dr. Seuss's *Green Eggs and Ham*, the adjective *green* modifies both the eggs and the ham. Unless the author used this incorrectly, this implies that there exist adjectives that inherently satisfy a distributive property over nouns; in other words, *Green Eggs and Ham* is equivalent to *Green Eggs and Green Ham*.

My question is: do all adjectives satisfy this property? If not, which ones do?

Also, more generally, is there a reference to the current "axioms" of English grammar that we use?

Comment: English isn’t algebra. Language doesn’t work that way. Grammar is messy, complex, not algebraically analyzable, and doesn’t this the kind of rules you’re thinking of. The phrase “green eggs and ham” is ambiguous: it could mean eggs that are green with normal ham, it could mean green eggs with green ham, and if “eggs and ham” were a fixed phrase, or a particular dish, it could mean something else altogether. If I write “green spotted dick”, does it mean someone needs antibiotics, or that it’s time to throw out that pudding?

Comment: Thank you, this response cleared up a lot of thoughts I had. I guess I am approaching English grammar with the wrong mindset. I just want to be able to better understand phrases (such as the one in my original question) that to me seem ambiguous.

Comment: It’s common to be lulled into this mindset; we see it all the time on this site. Unfortunately the hard fact is that English (I suspect all natural languages, but I am only familiar with English personally) is inherently, inevitably ambiguous. Hence for example, the creation of “legalese” (which can be all but incomprehensible unless you’re specifically trained it in, no matter how powerful your command of normal English might be). And even then ambiguities are identified, litigated, & captured in case law, which is then relied on in future disagreements, rather than the text.

Comment: Setting aside the OP's background and motivations for inquiring about this, there is a genuine question here that deserves an answer: are **all** adjectives liable to create this kind of a syntactical ambiguity (setting aside the fact that the context and/or some commonsense assumptions will usually provide a disambiguation), or are there some adjectives in English that inherently preclude it?

Comment: @jsw29 That's exactly what I was just wondering. If you ask that question, I will upvote it (assuming it's not a dupe)!

Comment: That Sam-I-Am, that Sam-I-Am!!

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205009/confusion-about-the-implied-repetition-or-not-of-an-adjective-in-a-parallel-co/205019#205019

Answer (score -1):

> Do adjectives in English satisfy a distributive property?

The short answer is “sometimes” the longer answer is:

“**And**” is not a true synonym of “**plus**”. And ~ together with; plus ~ combined with.

Although in maths, A(B+C) = AB + AC regardless of the value of B and C and its numerical type (2, -2½, Π) in English, Adjective(Noun1 + Noun2) depends on the values and type of B and C, i.e. A(B+C) is not necessarily equal to A(C+B) where + = and.

B and C may be singular and countable, plural, or uncountable.

As singulars we have *Give me a wet cloth and a spanner* -> the spanner is assumed not to be wet, but for clarity *Give me a spanner and a wet cloth.*.

As plurals we have *Give me wet cloths and spanners* – the spanner is, by default assumed to be wet.

If you do not want this to be the case, then *Give me spanners and wet cloths.*

As uncountable we have (i) *Give me detailed advice and spanners/a spanner* – the spanner is not assumed to be detailed. (ii)*Give me detailed advice and sympathy.* Sympathy is not assumed to be detailed.